# Avoiding variant name and type repetition in `enum`

Tags: enums, rust

I find myself often defining `enum` types like the following:

```
struct Foo { }
struct Bar { }
struct Baz { }

enum MyEnum {
    Foo(Foo),
    Bar(Bar),
    Baz(Baz),
}
```

I find the repetition of `Foo(Foo)` inelegant and redundant. It also makes initialization redundant:

```
let example = MyEnum::Foo(Foo{ /* ... */ });
```

I would like to instead write something like the following pseudocode:

```
struct Foo { }
struct Bar { }
struct Baz { }

type_enum MyEnum {
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Baz,
}

let example = MyEnum::Foo{ /* ...anything that `Foo` supports ... */ };
```

The above is very similar to `std::variant` in C++17. **Does Rust support anything like that?**

Comment: So what wrong with https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6c0e05fc4a108965e096ae37967c24d2 ?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I think there is one, but unfortunately I do not remember. Still, it shouldn't be too much code, so maybe you could just implement it yourself in your project.

Comment: Note that there is a major difference between `enum`s and `std::variant`: the ability to have different variants of the same contained type, which is very important for some uses of `enum`. I don't know how you could preserve that ability while also eliminating the perceived repetition here, which is probably why no related RFC has really gotten off the ground. I can also imagine interesting (=surprising) interactions with "anonymous `enum`s", which is another commonly asked for feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use this macro-based solution:

```
macro_rules! type_dispatch_enum{(enum $e: ident {$($v: ident,)*}) => {
    enum $e {
        $($v($v),)*
    }
    $(
        impl From<$v> for $e {
            fn from(v: $v) -> Self {
                $e::$v(v)
            }
        }
    )+
}}

struct S1 {}
struct S2;
struct S3(usize);

type_dispatch_enum!(enum E {
    S1,
    S2,
    S3,
});

fn take_e(e: E) {}

fn main() {
    take_e(S1{}.into());
    take_e(S2.into());
    take_e(S3(5).into());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An `enum` variant can be struct, tuple or unit struct. So you can simply define:

```rust
enum MyEnum {
    Foo {},
    Bar {},
    Baz {},
}
```

Or if you would like to define these variants as independent structs themselves, I'd argue that a more idiomatic 'functional' way is to use something like `Either`:

```rust
enum Either<L, R> {
    Left(L),
    Right(R),
}

struct Foo {}
struct Bar {}

type MyEnum = Either<Foo, Bar>;
```

There's a crate with the same name, but this basic definition should be sufficient most of the time.

Comment: I still want to use `Foo` and `Bar` independently of `MyEnum`. I don't see how the `Either` solution helps, as it still needs names for `L`and `R` (i.e. `Left` and `Right).

Comment: @VittorioRomeo nothing stops you from using Rust like C or C++. It is just that with more powerful language mechanisms like pattern matching, your concern here is mostly void. I happen to believe that it is more important to spell out the fact you are using a sum type.